# No configuration file found and no installation code available. Exiting... | Not true

Tags: database, .htaccess-configuration, configuration

I'm using **ALtervista** to host [my website](http://liceocroceromatest.altervista.org/joomla/).
I've just installed **joomla 2.5** using the auto-installation of Altervista.

**Exported** a database in `sql.gz` format and **imported** it into my new database on Altervista.

Then via **FTP**, using FileZilla, I **copied** everything that was in my old website and pasted it **into the /joomla folder** created by Altervista, **overriding** already existing files.

When done, I changed the configuration to the database on the `configuration.php` file and accidentally I read that phrase when trying to load my website: why is that?

Comment: Please ask me anything, but give me some feedback

Answer (score 1):

The error happens when Joomla can't read the `configuration.php` file, so it tries to check for an `installation` folder, but it doesn't find one.

Check if the `configuration.php` file is not an empty file - it might be that the FTP tool that you have used has corrupted the file. If everything's OK, then check the permissions and the ownership on the `configuration.php` file.

Comment: The file is not empty and its permissions are set as 664

Comment: What about the folder permissions? The folders need to have x set